# makefile - escape parentheses

Tags: windows, escaping, makefile, gnu-make

I have a folder on my HD which contains parentheses in its name. Like: `C:/stuff (really cool)/`. The make `$(wildcard ..)` function does not work properly with this directory.

```
$(wildcard C:/stuff (really cool)/*.jpg)`
```

evaluates to no results at all. I guess this is due to the fact that the closing parentheses in the directory-name is treated as the closing parentheses for the `$(wildcard ..)` function. Escaping the `(` and `)` with a backslash does not work. What also does not work, is putting the directory-name into a variable and then using the wildcard function.

```
DIR = C:/stuff (really cool)
all:
    @echo "$(wildcard $(DIR)/*.jpg)"
```

No results at all, again.

How should I properly escape the parentheses?

Comment: The path separator in Windows is a backslash.  Avoid assuming that a forward slash works in ancient tooling like this.

Comment: Could you cut the knot with a symbolic link?

Answer (score 0):

The following does not work, kept to warn others:

Special characters are typically "protected", or escaped, with enclosing quotes. To create a variable with parenthesis, you use double quotes.

```
DIR = "C:/stuff (really cool)"
```

In your case, the biggest problem is the spaces that will result in your path being broken down into several parts instead of one.

This works:

GNU Make lets you escape spaces with `\\` so your call to `$wildcard` would turn into

```
$(wildcard C:/stuff\\ (really\\ cool)/*.jpg)
```

Comment: That doesn't work for me. `dir = "C:/stuff (really cool)" ;; foo = $(wildcard $(dir)/*)`; `$(foo)`is empty.

Answer (score 0):

You did not mention in what kind of environment you are running, but both of the following print mechanism work for me from a regular DOS prompt as well as from msys/mingw:

```
DIR = C:/stuff\ (really\ cool)
$(info Files in subdir are: $(wildcard $(DIR)/*.jpg))

all:
    @echo "Files in subdir are: $(wildcard $(DIR)/*.jpg)"
```

The double quotes around the `echo`-ed expression are only necessary for msys/mingw.